# Are Extension methods an example of Visitor Pattern?

Tags: extension-methods, visitor-pattern

Both these concepts have one thing in common,which is extending an operation and define it elsewhere in a separate class.But I think extension methods are not a real world example of implementation of Visitor pattern.Can someone explain this?
Is there a connection between Visitor pattern and Extension methods?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say that there is any direct relation between Visitor Pattern and Extension Methods but there are similarities.

Visitor Pattern's intent is to allow easy addition of an operation on the elements of an object structure without modifying the different elements themselves. The major benefit is because an object structure like an xml will have different types of nodes. If you want to add an operation on each node then you'd have to implement it in all the nodes across different classes. Using the pattern you could centralize that inside the Visitors. On the other hand extension methods focus on a single class only.

Similarities are that in both extension methods and visitor classes you don't have access to the private fields of the class.

In my line of work I have not met a case where I needed to apply Visitor pattern but on the other hand I used Extensions quite frequently. Only recently I was implementing an [Active Record](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) extensions for some of my models for which Extension methods really helped.

Hence I'd say the similarity between them is that they facilitate extending behavior's to a class/group of classes and the similarity pretty much ends there.